# Dispersion, surface acoustic wave devices

Tags: waves, acoustics, dispersion

I am trying to understand dispersion, and to do it within the context of surface acoustic waves (SAWs).
For surface acoustic wave devices the inter-digital transducers (IDTs) produce Rayleigh waves that travel along the surface.

However within this system, depending on the substrate material, there will be some other acoustic wave types observed, (bulk, Love, etc.) but with typically with a lower energy.

Acoustic dispersion as I understand from Wikipedia is a sound wave separating into component frequencies as it passes through a materials. Would some of these other acoustic signals be dispersion of the original surface wave? I think some might be produced inadvertently by the IDTs.

---

Edit to address a comment. IDTs are inter-digital transducers, a metallic pattern of interlocking fingers used to produce surface wave on a piezoelectric substrate. 
The question is looking for explanation of acoustic dispersion with relation to SAWs specifically.

Comment: Could you provide the definition of  IDTs? Also, it's not clear to me: are you asking what dispersion is?

Comment: Inter-digital transducer (IDT), they are a pattern of interlocking metallic fingers on top of a piezoelectric substrate. And yes I am looking for clarification on what acoustic dispersion is, but within the specific context of surface acoustic wave type devices. @nicoguaro

Comment: Those details should be in the question then.